# cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'pattern' is not allowed to appear in element 'security:http'

Tags: java, spring-security, okta-api

Below is my securityContext.xml but i am not able to catch the error why it is throwing the error, i am new to springsecurity , please help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- Enable auto-wiring -->
<context:annotation-config/>

<!-- Scan for auto-wiring classes in spring saml packages -->
<context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.security.saml"/>

 <!-- MK - This is commented in CG -->
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />

<!-- MK - Copied from security-ldap.xml -->
<security:http pattern="/login.jsp" security="none" />
<security:http pattern="/app/css/**" security="none" />
<security:http pattern="/app/font/**" security="none" />
<security:http pattern="/app/images/**" security="none" />
<security:http pattern="/app/json/**" security="none" />
<security:http pattern="/vs_lib/**" security="none" />
<security:http pattern="/401.jsp" security="none" />
<security:http pattern="/404.jsp" security="none" />
<security:http pattern="/4500.jsp" security="none" />


<!-- Unsecured pages -->
  <security:http security="none" pattern="/favicon.ico"/>
<security:http security="none" pattern="/images/**"/>
<security:http security="none" pattern="/css/**"/>
<security:http security="none" pattern="/logout.jsp"/>

<!-- MK - This is un commented in CG -->
<!-- Security for the administration UI -->
<!--<security:http pattern="/saml/web/**" use-expressions="false">
    <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/saml/web/metadata/login"/>
    <security:form-login login-processing-url="/saml/web/login" login-page="/saml/web/metadata/login" default-target-url="/saml/web/metadata"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/saml/web/metadata/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/saml/web/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <security:custom-filter before="FIRST" ref="metadataGeneratorFilter"/>
</security:http> -->

<!-- Secured pages with SAML as entry point -->
 <!-- MK - Modified this -->
<security:http entry-point-ref="samlEntryPoint" use-expressions="false">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
    <security:custom-filter before="FIRST" ref="metadataGeneratorFilter"/>
    <security:custom-filter after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="samlFilter"/>
</security:http>

<!-- Filters for processing of SAML messages -->
<bean id="samlFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <security:filter-chain-map request-matcher="ant">
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/metadata/**" filters="metadataDisplayFilter"/>
        <!--<security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SingleLogout/**" filters="samlLogoutProcessingFiler"/> -->
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/login/**" filters="samlEntryPoint"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/logout/**" filters="samlLogoutFilter"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SSO/**" filters="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SSOHoK/**" filters="samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/discovery/**" filters="samlIDPDiscovery"/>
    </security:filter-chain-map>
</bean>

<!-- Handler deciding where to redirect user after successful login -->
<bean id="successRedirectHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/"/>
</bean>
<!--
Use the following for interpreting RelayState coming from unsolicited response as redirect URL:
<bean id="successRedirectHandler" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLRelayStateSuccessHandler">
   <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/" />
</bean>
-->

<!-- Handler deciding where to redirect user after failed login -->
<bean id="failureRedirectHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <property name="useForward" value="true"/>
    <!-- MK - CG refrence updated value-->
    <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/jsp/useraccess.jsp"/>
</bean>


<!-- Handler for successful logout -->
<bean id="successLogoutHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler">
<!-- MK - CG refrence updated value-->
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/logout.jsp"/>
</bean>



<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <!-- Register authentication manager for SAML provider -->
    <security:authentication-provider ref="samlAuthenticationProvider"/>
    <!-- Register authentication manager for administration UI --> 
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service id="adminInterfaceService">
            <security:user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager> 

<!-- Logger for SAML messages and events -->
<bean id="samlLogger" class="org.springframework.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger"/>

<!-- Central storage of cryptographic keys -->
<bean id="keyManager" class="org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager">
    <constructor-arg value="classpath:security/samlKeystore.jks"/>
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="nalle123"/>
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="apollo" value="nalle123"/>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="apollo"/>
</bean>

<!-- Entry point to initialize authentication, default values taken from properties file -->
<bean id="samlEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint">
    <property name="defaultProfileOptions">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileOptions">
            <property name="includeScoping" value="false"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- IDP Discovery Service -->
<!-- SS Modifed the path of idp .jsp -->
<bean id="samlIDPDiscovery" 
class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLDiscovery">
    <property name="idpSelectionPath" 
value="classpath:security/idpSelection.jsp"/>
</bean>
<!-- SS modified property name idpDiscoveryEnabled value false referenc CG--
>
<!-- Filter automatically generates default SP metadata -->
<bean id="metadataGeneratorFilter" 
class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean 
class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator">
            <property name="extendedMetadata">
                <bean 
class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                    <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="false"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<!-- The filter is waiting for connections on URL suffixed with filterSuffix 
and presents SP metadata there -->
<bean id="metadataDisplayFilter" 
class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataDisplayFilter"/>

<!-- Configure HTTP Client to accept certificates from the keystore for 
HTTPS verification -->
<!--
<bean 
class="org.springframework.security.saml.trust.httpclient.
TLSProtocolConfigurer"
>
    <property name="sslHostnameVerification" value="default"/>
</bean>
-->

<!-- IDP Metadata configuration - paths to metadata of IDPs in circle of trust is here -->
<bean id="metadata" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
           <!-- <property name="defaultIDP" value="https://nshobayo.oktapreview.com/"/> -->

    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider">
              <!-- URL containing the metadata -->
              <constructor-arg>
                <!-- This URL should look something like this: https://dev-502573.oktapreview.com/app/abc0defghijK1lmN23o4/sso/saml/metadata -->
                <value type="java.lang.String">https://<URL>/sso/saml/metadata</value>
              </constructor-arg>
              <!-- Timeout for metadata loading in ms -->
              <constructor-arg>
                <value type="int">5000</value>
              </constructor-arg>
              <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
            </bean>
            <!-- Example of file system metadata without Extended Metadata -->
            <!--
            <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <value type="java.io.File">/usr/local/metadata/idp.xml</value>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
            </bean>
            -->
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
    <!-- OPTIONAL used when one of the metadata files contains information about this service provider -->
    <!-- <property name="hostedSPName" value=""/> -->
    <!-- OPTIONAL property: can tell the system which IDP should be used for authenticating user by default. -->
</bean>

<!-- SAML Authentication Provider responsible for validating of received SAML messages -->
<bean id="samlAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider">
    <!-- OPTIONAL property: can be used to store/load user data after login -->
    <!-- MK - CG refrence updated value-->
    <!--
  <property name="userDetails" ref="customUserDetailService" />
<property name="forcePrincipalAsString" value="false" /> 
-->
</bean>

<!-- Provider of default SAML Context -->
<bean id="contextProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderImpl"/>

<!-- Processing filter for WebSSO profile messages -->
<bean id="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successRedirectHandler"/>
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureRedirectHandler"/>
</bean>

<!-- Processing filter for WebSSO Holder-of-Key profile -->
<bean id="samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successRedirectHandler"/>
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureRedirectHandler"/>
</bean>

<!-- Logout handler terminating local session -->
<bean id="logoutHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler">
    <property name="invalidateHttpSession" value="false"/>
</bean>

<!-- Override default logout processing filter with the one processing SAML messages -->
<bean id="samlLogoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutFilter">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="successLogoutHandler"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="logoutHandler"/>
    <constructor-arg index="2" ref="logoutHandler"/>
</bean>

<!-- Filter processing incoming logout messages -->
<!-- First argument determines URL user will be redirected to after successful global logout -->
<bean id="samlLogoutProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="successLogoutHandler"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="logoutHandler"/>
</bean>

<!-- Class loading incoming SAML messages from httpRequest stream -->
<bean id="processor" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="redirectBinding"/>
            <ref bean="postBinding"/>
            <ref bean="artifactBinding"/>
            <ref bean="soapBinding"/>
            <ref bean="paosBinding"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<!-- SAML 2.0 WebSSO Assertion Consumer -->
<bean id="webSSOprofileConsumer" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl"/>

<!-- SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key WebSSO Assertion Consumer -->
<bean id="hokWebSSOprofileConsumer" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl"/>

<!-- SAML 2.0 Web SSO profile -->
<bean id="webSSOprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileImpl"/>

<!-- SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key Web SSO profile -->
<bean id="hokWebSSOProfile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl"/>

<!-- SAML 2.0 ECP profile -->
<bean id="ecpprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileECPImpl"/>

<!-- SAML 2.0 Logout Profile -->
<bean id="logoutprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.SingleLogoutProfileImpl"/>

<!-- Bindings, encoders and decoders used for creating and parsing messages -->
<bean id="postBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPPostBinding">
    <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="velocityEngine"/>
</bean>

<bean id="redirectBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding">
    <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
</bean>

<bean id="artifactBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPArtifactBinding">
    <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="velocityEngine"/>
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager"/>
                    </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
            <property name="processor">
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl">
                    <constructor-arg ref="soapBinding"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="soapBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPSOAP11Binding">
    <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
</bean>

<bean id="paosBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPPAOS11Binding">
    <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
</bean>

<!-- Initialization of OpenSAML library-->
<bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLBootstrap"/>

<!-- Initialization of the velocity engine -->
<bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.security.saml.util.VelocityFactory" factory-method="getEngine"/>

<!-- XML parser pool needed for OpenSAML parsing -->
<bean id="parserPool" class="org.opensaml.xml.parse.StaticBasicParserPool" init-method="initialize">
    <property name="builderFeatures">
        <map>
            <entry key="http://apache.org/xml/features/dom/defer-node-expansion" value="false"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="parserPoolHolder" class="org.springframework.security.saml.parser.ParserPoolHolder"/>
```

The error i am getting is :

- org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader           | Context 
  initialization failed
  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 
  19 in XML document from class path resource [security/securityContext.xml] 
  is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 
  19; columnNumber: 56; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'pattern' is not 
  allowed to appear in element 'security:http'.

Comment: I wrote a tutorial on how to use Spring Boot and Spring Security with SAML and JavaConfig. Maybe this will help? https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/03/16/spring-boot-saml

Comment: @dur : I have copied the complete XML. The validation is successful also. Please suggest

Comment: @dur : yes it has closing tag